Potential massive bug in Visual Studio /.net core?
I have an application with a custom control. The OnLoad() event handler adds an item to a list owned by the control. If I stop debugging and restart, the list contains the items it had from the previous execution.
Public Class Display
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    Public Objects As New List(Of Object)

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        Objects.Add(New Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10))
    End Sub
End Class

In this case, when I debug the application and put a breakpoint on the Objects.Add() line, a watch on the Objects list shows it already has several objects from the previous debugging session; the list gets bigger on every subsequent execution. It isn't a graphical glitch either, a later piece of code that loops on the objects does indeed loop on all objects in the list, including those from the previous debug session. This seems like a very fundamental bug. Is this correct?
Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.5

Unlikely, but....  You need to produce a [MRE] to demonstrate your massive bug, not a few lines of code with no context. And if it is a bug, log it on the DotNetCore Github Repo - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues.

It's not correct. If it's a "massive bug", the problem is in the question's code. .NET and Windows Forms exists for 22 years and used by hundreds of thousands if not millions of developers. You haven't posted anything that shows incrementing memory, much less that the process memory remains active even after the process itself terminates, and is reused in the next debugging session, whatever that may mean

If you start an application through the debugger, stopping also stops the application. In that case the OS, not Visual Studio, releases the memory and all handles. Nothing remains. If on the other hand you attach the debugger to an already running application and then detach, the process isn't stopped

How do you use the Display class? Are you creating new forms as needed, or are you using the same default instance over and over? If you use the same default Form instance then yes, all fields retain their values. That's not a bug. You're using a singleton class without clearing it. Few people do this they have to not just clear the old data but reload the new one. It only saves time in very small applications. That's a VB quirk that exists to keep compatibility with how VB6 worked. C# has no default instances

In its most basic form, it is a Form with a single instance of 'Display' added using the GUI editor. The application was started using the green 'Run' button, and stopped with the red 'Stop' button. These should have completely started and closed out the debugged instance. Now more interestingly, after restarting VS, the problem doesn't remain. So it is a transient thing, but still something that should surely be impossible.

Sounds like you may have started debugging use Reattach to Process instead of a new run of the application, so the application doesn't close when you press Stop, only the debugger detaches.

I agree it sounds like that, though I'd not expect the UI to have that mapping, especially unannounced like it did. One thought is that the application did have some multi-threading, so perhaps some threads were still running and keeping the application alive between executions.

Make sure the Objects list is not declared as Shared or Static anywhere in your code You can try explicitly clearing the list in the OnLoad event before adding new items. This ensures that the list is reset every time the control is loaded.
Public Shared Objects As New List(Of Object)
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Objects.Clear() ' Clears the list before adding a new object
    Objects.Add(New Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10))
    End


If the application is stopped, no memory remains, no matter how the fields are declared. If the OP sees "old" data, they aren't stopping the application. And quite likely, they're reusing the form object
